# JSON files beeing read twice instead of once in JAVA

Tags: java, json

I am building a connector to read JSON files and write in the database. My problem is that it writes everything double, that is if there are 2 files it reads them twice, 3 files 3X and soo on..
*edited with more info and parts where it writes in the database.Altough I think the problem lies in my many for loops but have not been able to resolve it.  Here is almost my full code:

```java
public void collectData(File file, Map<String, String> args)
          throws FileNotFoundException, IOException,SQLException 
  {
// reading the JSON file
          File folder = new File(sourcepath);// where Inubit will save the files
          File[] fileNames = folder.listFiles();

          // go through all files
          for (File jsonInputFile : fileNames) {
              if (jsonInputFile.getName().toString().startsWith("Metadata_JSON3")) {
                  System.out.println("JSON File: " + jsonInputFile);
              } else {
                  System.out.println("Not correct JSON file" + jsonInputFile);
                  continue;
              } // filter non JSON Files

              // setting JSON parser
              JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
              JSONParser parser2 = new JSONParser();
              FileReader reader = new FileReader(jsonInputFile);
              Object obj = null;
              try {
                  obj = parser.parse(reader);
              } catch (Exception e) {
              }
              try {
                  jsonarray = (JSONArray) obj;
              } catch (Exception p1) {
                  String objcast = "[" + obj + "]";

                  try {
                      jsonarray = (JSONArray) parser2.parse(objcast);
                  } catch (ParseException e) {
                      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }
              // starting to read the JSON file
              for (Object valuesObj : jsonarray) {
                  JSONObject values2 = (JSONObject) valuesObj;

                  // getting points
                  JSONArray row = (JSONArray) values2.get("row");
                  for (int i = 0; i < row.size(); i++) {
                      JSONObject rows = (JSONObject) row.get(i);
                      Long Curve_id = (Long) rows.get("CURVE_ID");
                      String Curve_id_str = Long.toString(Curve_id);
                      ts_info_map.put("Curve_id_m", Curve_id_str);
                      // System.out.println("Curve_id is: " + Curve_id);
                      String Curve_name = (String) rows.get("CURVE_NAME");
                      ts_info_map.put("Curve_name_m", Curve_name);
                      String Value_frequency_is = (String) rows.get("META.Value.Frequency.is");
                      ts_info_map.put("Value_frequency_is_m", Value_frequency_is);
                      String Issue_frequency_is = (String) rows.get("META.Issue.Frequency.is");
                      ts_info_map.put("Issue_frequency_is_m", Issue_frequency_is);
                      String Timezone = (String) rows.get("META.Timezone.is");
                      ts_info_map.put("Timezone_m", Timezone);
                  } // third for loop
              }// second for loop

              try {
                  reader.close();
                  parser.reset();
                  // parser2.reset();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  System.out.println("reader or parser cannot be closed");
                  // nothing... sometimes not possible to close reader
              }

          }// end of first for loop
      }

@Override
  public void collectInfo(File file, Map<String, String> args)
          throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
  @Override
  public void refreshInfo(File file, Map<String, String> args)
          throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      this.ts_info_map.clear();
      try {
          collectData(file, args);
      } catch (SQLException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void insertData(int runid, int subrunid, Map<String, String> args)
          throws SQLException {

      try {
      String datatable  = args.get("datatable");
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL, DBUSER, DBPASS);
      String sql = "insert into "
              + datatable
              + " (run_id,subrun_id,CURVE_ID, CURVE_NAME, VALUE_FREQUENCY_IS, ISSUE_FREQUENCY_IS, TIMEZONE_IS) values "
              + " (?" + StringUtils.repeat(",?", 7 - 1) + ")";

      PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

          // prepare sql statement 
          ps.setInt(1, runid);
          ps.setInt(2, subrunid);
          ps.setString(3, ts_info_map.get("Curve_id_m"));
          ps.setString(4,ts_info_map.get("Curve_name_m"));
          ps.setString(5,ts_info_map.get("Value_frequency_is_m"));
          ps.setString(6,ts_info_map.get("Issue_frequency_is_m"));
          ps.setString(7,ts_info_map.get("Timezone_m"));

ps.addBatch();

      ps.executeBatch(); //writes in table
      ps.close();
      con.close();

      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("insert data exception" +e);}
  }
```

Comment: what's with the weird indentation? it's very hard to read the code and understand the flow (for a human)

Comment: Please add the code before this piece. This code is only parsing , it may be an issue in database update too.

Comment: Thanks @Kris I have added almost all info now.

Comment: Well what is this variable "ts_info_map". If its a map, it does not make sense to over-write it every iteration of loop 3!

Comment: @Kris yes, it is a map : private Map<String, String> ts_info_map = new HashMap<String, String>();  How do I avoid overwriting it?

Comment: can't you use an object? What i doubt is you are writing the same object (since its over-written) n times (n=filecount) to the db. Your aim is to write each file content to db, but same content will be written for each file. Consider an object instead of map or use something like Map<String, Map<String,String>

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the problem. I had a main program that calls the collect data part for each file and then also the for loop in the collect data part so that caused the double writting. So I just removed the loop:

```java
for (File jsonInputFile : fileNames) {// just removed this line

            if (jsonInputFile.getName().toString().startsWith("Metadata_JSON3")) {
                System.out.println("JSON File: " + jsonInputFile);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not correct JSON file" + jsonInputFile);
                continue;
            } // filter non JSON Files

            // setting JSON parser
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            JSONParser parser2 = new JSONParser();
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(jsonInputFile);
            Object obj = null;
            try {
                obj = parser.parse(reader);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
.....


//also used the hash map to write the data in

for (Integer i = 0; i < row.size(); i++) {
              HashMap<String, String> row_map = new HashMap<String, String>();

              JSONObject rows = (JSONObject) row.get(i);
              Long Curve_id = (Long) rows.get("CURVE_ID");
              String Curve_id_str = Long.toString(Curve_id);
              row_map.put("Curve_id_m", Curve_id_str);
              row_map.put("Curve_name_m", (String) rows.get("CURVE_NAME"));

....
//the rest remained more or less the same as it was before
```